# Create a nested table with a shared header row in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am looking to create a table where some of columns correspond to a nested array of values. Essentially I am looking to represent the following data structure in a single table:

```js
[{
    "ValueID": 3,
    "NumberHits": 11,
    "MoreData": [{
        "SubTable1": "R0002",
        "SubTable2": 10,
        "SubTable3": 22,
        "SubTable4": 100
      },
      {
        "SubTable1": "GoogleTime22212",
        "SubTable2": 200,
        "SubTable3": 1234,
        "SubTable4": 10
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ValueID": 1,
    "NumberHits": 11,
    "MoreData": [{
      "SubTable1": "sev",
      "SubTable2": 0,
      "SubTable3": 22,
      "SubTable4": 100
    }]
  }
]
```

The closest approximation I have been able to generate in HTML (via a React component) looks like this [Close Table appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfMf0.png):

[image]

As you can see the data is all visible but not properly aligned as the outer table is not aligned with the elements within the inner table

Having removed class names and id values for brevity, the html for constructing this table is as follows:

```html
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="rh">Item #</td>
        <td class="rh"><span>Value ID</span></td>
        <td class="rh"><span>Number of Hits</span></td>
        <td class="rh"><span></span><span>SubTable1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span>SubTable2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span>SubTable3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span>SubTable4&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div >
                <td class="container">
                    <div id="index-0" >1</div>
                </td>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><div><span>3</span></div></td>
        <td><div><span>11</span></div></td>
        <td>
            <div >
                <table  cellspacing="0"  style="table-layout: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="0">
                            <td><div><span>R0002</span></div></td>
                            <td><div><span>10</span></div></td>
                            <td><div><span>22</span></div></td>
                            <td><div><span>100</span></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="1">
                            <td><div><span>GoogleTime22212</span></div></td>
                            <td><div><span>200</span></div></td>
                            <td><div><span>1,234</span></div></td>
                            <td><div><span>10</span></div></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div >
                <td>
                    <div>2</div>
                </td>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div><span>1</span></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div><span>11</span></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div >
                <table  cellspacing="0"  style="table-layout: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="0">
                            <td><div><span>sev</span></div></td>
                            <td><div><span>0</span></div></td>
                            <td><div><span>22</span></div></td>
                            <td><div><span>100</span></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is obviously not correct but is the closest I could hack together to represent the idea of what I am looking to accomplish. Does there exist a more elegant solution to have the top row of item headers align with the elements in the table bellow?

Comment: You've posted various things (thank you!) but I'm not sure what the end-result should be, or what it should look like; could you add the details of the desired result? An image, perhaps? Or the HTML you want, that should be generated?

Comment: @DavidThomas the idea is that it should look almost exactly as it does in the image attached, but the elements in the table ought to be aligned under the headers above it. Right now there is no relation between these elements and so it has no way to keep the items in the table from being off-center, which should be apparent in the image I provided.

Comment: Thanks, but that's a description of a layout which is open to ambiguities; can you - *please* - share either the desired resultant HTML your code should result in, or at the very least a picture of the desired result?